# variable overwrite when reading from database

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

I have a meny.php file who loads in with ajax the selected link to the div with id=content as you can see before the footer is included. This code is working and it´s nothing spacial with that. I just think this code may be helpfull.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    include 'includes/head.php';
?>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            /* This is basic - uses default settings */

            $("a.single_image").fancybox();

            /* Using custom settings */

            $("a#inline").fancybox({
                'hideOnContentClick': true
            });

            /* Apply fancybox to multiple items */

            $("a.group").fancybox({
                'href'   : '#fancybox-inner',
                'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
                'speedIn'       :   600, 
                'speedOut'      :   200, 
                'overlayShow'   :   false
            });
            $("a.single_image").fancybox({
                'href'   : '#fancybox-inner',
                'titleShow'  : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
            });
        });

        $(function(){
        // hide the div on page load and use a slidedown effect
        $('div.content').fadeOut(0, function(){
            $(this).slideDown(500);
        });


        // capture link clicks and slide up then go to the links href attribute
        $('a.slide_page1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $href = $(this).attr('href');
            $('div.content').slideUp(500, function(){
              //  window.location = $href;
               // alert($href);
            });
        });





    });
    </script>
    <div class="page">
        <?php
            include 'includes/header.php';
        ?>
        <div class="container-fluid" id = "bodu">
     <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">            
        <div class="bodu">



            <div class="blog">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <div class="span2" id ="sidebarspan">
                                    <h2>Meny</h2>
                                    <ul id="nav">
                                        <li id ="sidebar">
                                            <a href="hamburgare">Hamburgare</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id ="sidebar">
                                             <a href="maltider">Måltider</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id ="sidebar">
                                            <a href="dryck">Dryck</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id ="sidebar">
                                            <a href="tillbehor">Tillbehör</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id ="sidebar">
                                            <a href="desserter">Desserter</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li id ="sidebar">
                                            <a href="övrigt">Övrigt</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="span10">
                                <div id = "content" class="content"> 
                                  <script src="jquery/general.js"></script>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
        <?php
            include 'includes/footer.php';
        ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bg-bottom" >
            <img src="images/bg-bottom.png" alt="bottom">
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now for the real problem. Lets say we selected the "hamburgere" from the meny.php. It will then try to load in like I said with ajax the hamburgare.php file. That file looks like this

```
    <?php
include '../includes/head.php';


?>


<h1>Hamburgare!</h1>
<p>hamburgare är gott!</p>

<div class="row-fluid" id = "meals">
<div class="span12" id="right-pane">
    <?php

        $select = "SELECT * FROM hamburgare";
        $sql = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());


        mysql_num_rows($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {


            $name = "<name>".$row['name']."</name>";
            $price = "<price>".$row['price']."</price>";
            $description = "<description>".$row['description']."                </description>";
            $img = $row['image'];

            $event = " <a name='$img' class='single_image' href='fancybox-inner' ><img       src='Login/$img'/></a>";
            echo $event;
             /*closing the whileloop*/
        }


    ?>
</div>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
                <div id="fancybox-inner">

                    <?php
                        $query = mysql_query('SELECT name FROM hamburgare WHERE image = "' . $img . '"');

                    ?>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row-fluid">
                            <h2><?php echo $query ?></h2>
                            <h2><?php echo $name ?></h2>
                            <div class="span4">
                                <img src="Login/<?php echo $img; ?>" />
                            <!--Sidebar content-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="span8">
                                <?php echo $description ?>
                            <!--Body content-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

What I am trying to do here is to load all the images from the hamburgare table in the database and for now i am just printing them out in the while loop in a a-tag. Thats working fine but when a customer clicks on one of the images more specific information shall be shown to the customer.
What happens here is when you click on one of the images the fancybox-inner div is shown but the information the fancybox-inner contains is about the last loaded image. That means it doesn´t matter witch image is selected it will always show information about the last loaded image. 
The reason is because the WHERE Clause in the last SQL query, I compare the the last loaded image ($img) who is equal to the one in the database. So what happens is I get this overlapping problem. Also I compare with $img and not the name = $img from the showsen a-tag, who I dont know how to write as a SQL query.

How ever I think the problem is bigger than that. The only thing I do is hiding the fancybox-inner div and just show it when some of the images is selected. That code is stil executed from the start. So I thing I needs Jquery/AJAX to load right information for each image. So I think I need to add onClick for each a-tag in the while-loop.
But since I am new in this stuff I dont know how to write that code. Maybe my hypothesis is wrong as well. I dont know.

What do you guys think? I will appreciate all kinds of help.

thanks in advance

Comment: You're overwriting `$name, $descriptions, $image` etc in `while` loop that's why you will get only last value in that loop.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (_mysql_*_ functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (_mysqli_*_ functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: You are not using the return value of `mysql_num_rows()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the returned values to an array first and do the output later.

For example:

```
$formattedResults = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ) )
{
    $formattedResults[] = array(
        'name' => sprintf( '<name>%s</name>', $row['name'] ),
        'price' => sprintf( '<price>%s</price>', $row['price'] ),
        'description' => sprintf( '<description>%s</description>', $row['description'] ),
        'img' => $row['image'],
        'event' => sprintf( '<a name="%s" class="single_image" href="fancybox-inner" ><img src="Login/%s"/></a>', $row['image'], $row['image'] ),
    );
}

var_dump( $formattedResults );
```

Comment: Ok. Thats a good ide, but when i need the output later how shall I get the right output? like this 

    $keys = array_keys($formattedResults);
foreach($keys as %s) {
    echo(%s);
}

Comment: Use the id from your database to keep track of which image the user has clicked on. So like you save name in an array, also save id. Then do a for loop to iterate through the array.